# The correct way to build an external link & prevent scam complaints

Tags: html, redirect

I have one old project with the forum, blogs, and other user-generated content.
All the external links there are replaced with `/click.php?url=targetUrlHere`. The `click.php` it the very simple:

```
<?php

$url = $_REQUEST["url"];

if (!preg_match("/^https?:\/\//",$url))
    $url = "http://" . $url;

header("Location: " . urldecode($url));
```

This approach worked for years, and in case of spam or scam the user content was removed together with the link.

Suddenly I started getting complains from the hoster that are related to the `/click.php` page directly, like this one: https://incident.netcraft.com/b1c233233fc5/

What should I do with that?

Should I create a separate page with the 'You are going to leave the system, are you sure?' And place a button and javascript redirect there? Will it help?

Or are there any redirect services that check the link for scam against some databases before allowing the redirect?

Comment: Why do you need `/click.php` in the first place?

Comment: I think that initially it was used for preventing PageRank loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [open redirects can be considered a security vulnerability](https://youtu.be/4Jk_I-cw4WE). Suppose a user knows and trusts `good.example`. Someone sends that user a link like `https://good.example/click.php?url=%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%62%61%64%2e%65%78%61%6d%70%6c%65`. The user trusts `good.example`, so it clicks it, but it gets redirected to `http://bad.example/`, which can impersonate `good.example` or worse, download a malware and redirect to your site immediately.

---

I suggest removing `/click.php` entirely and instead make user-generated hyperlinks in this format:

```html
<a href="url" rel="nofollow">link text</a>
```

> The `nofollow` link type indicates that the linked document is not endorsed by the author of this one, for example if it has no control over it, if it is a bad example or if there is commercial relationship between the two (sold link). This link type may be used by some search engines that use popularity ranking techniques.

— [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types)

You may also add the `external` link type if the link points to another site (usually another domain) and `noreferrer` and `noopener` if you don't want the linked site to know that the user came from yours.

---

If you plan to continue using `/click.php`, yes, you should place a notice to indicate that the user is going to leave your site and you can also show the destination URL to the user. That's what Google does:

https://www.google.com/url?q=%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%62%61%64%2e%65%78%61%6d%70%6c%65